# Spring Security 3.x: Creating a custom authentication provider without a UserDetailsService

Tags: java, spring-security

I created a custom authentication provider by extending `AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider` that authenticates the user against the database and performs additional authorization checks.

The annoyance I'm facing is the authentication provider requires me to wire a `UserDetailsService`. At least for this project, I have no needs for `UserDetailsService` because if I have the authentication provider to pull the user information to perform authentication/authorization, I don't see a need to have the `UserDetailsService` to pull the same user information to construct the `UserDetails` object.

So, right now, I have to wire a dummy `UserDetailsService` into my authentication provider and it does absolutely nothing.

Is it possible to create an authentication provider without a `UserDetailsService`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the code for AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider (at least for version 3.0.5) it is not requiring UserDetailsService to be wired.   Double check your XML configuration to make sure the DAOAuthenticationProvider is not being used.

You should have a block like this

```
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider ref="yourAuthenticationProvider" />
</authentication-manager>
```

Also, log the exception you are getting to see exactly where it's getting thrown from.

Comment: When you do a custom authentication provider, I believe at least one UserDetailsService has to be registered.  I tried to get it to work without and couldn't figure out a way.  `Factory method [org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService org.springframework.security.config.http.UserDetailsServiceFactoryBean.cachingUserDetailsService(java.lang.String)] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: No UserDetailsService registered.`

Comment: What class is throwing the nested exception?

Answer (score 0):

The default authentication provider used by Spring will be `DaoAuthenticationProvider` (which extend `AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider` and does add some checks of it's own in `doAfterPropertiesSet()`).

So that implementation does require a `UserDetailsService` but you can always just provide your own implementation of the provider, by extending `AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider`.

Comment: he actually described in his post that he already did that - extended AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider